# Как сделать ограниченное количество строк в табличной части?

Tags: 1с, таблицы

Как сделать ограничение количества строк в таблице, т.е. максимальное количество записей в таблице = 5. Пытался сделать так, но выдает ошибку:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура СоставПередНачаломДобавления(Элемент, Отказ, Копирование)

    Если Состав.Количество() > 5 Тогда
        Отказ = Истина;
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью приложения: создать единый интерфейс работы с этой таблицей, в котором контролировать количество строк при добавлении. Все функции приложения, которые могут добавлять строки в эту таблицу, должны работать через этот интерфейс.

Другой вариант - сделать обработку события добавления записей в СУБД, которая используется 1С.

Comment: Можете дополнить ваш ответ, как на платформе 1с сделать следующее: " создать единый интерфейс работы с этой таблицей"?

Answer (score 0):

Обращайтесь к табличной части через "Объект", так можно обойтись процедурой на клиенте.

Пример для внешней обработки:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура СоставПередНачаломДобавленияй(Элемент, Отказ, Копирование, Родитель, Группа, Параметр)
    Если Объект.Состав.Количество() >= 5 Тогда
        Отказ = истина;
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```